# Как применить шрифт к utf символу

Tags: css3, html5

Есть utf символ ∞.
Я его поместил в спан, в css задаю этому спану font: жирность, размер, шрифт
На выходе получаю пшик, символ всё такой же уродливый.
Суть вопроса такая, у десктопного вк этот символ в шрифте Roboto, у меня же не работает, так же не работает open sans. Почему и как подключить?
Зато работает potta one, но это совсем не то что мне нужно
Пробовал подключать Roboto в разных стилях и жирности, 0 реакции

Answer (score 0):

вот так делаете?

```css
.block1 {
  font: 700 92px Roboto;
}

.block2 {
  font: 700 92px 'open sans';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class = 'block1'>∞</span>
<br>
<span class = 'block2'>∞</span>
```

Comment: Open sans не применяется, но Roboto применился, я его убрал из импорта и это сработало